# Laravel Nova: Change RouteKeyName to UUID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, uuid, laravel-nova

Is there a way to change the default RouteKey Name from ID to an UUID within Laravel Nova?

On my default Model, this is already changed but I would like to also change it within the Laravel Nova Backend.

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
 return 'uuid';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the answer to this is **No**.

That said, the Laravel Nova framework could certainly be extended to support this functionality.

The code for this is part of the `InteractsWithResources` concern, where there's a `findModelKey` method, which uses a `whereKey` method, which pairs against the primary key, rather than the route key.

I'm sure that we could petition the Laravel framework to add a `whereRouteKey` to Eloquent query builders, and then suggest the Nova framework to use the new `whereRouteKey` instead of the `whereKey` method.

Short of this, the only other alternative is to rebind the Nova Request with one of your own design, which has a high level of effort, and frankly isn't best practice.

With all of this in mind, I would sort of expect this functionality out of the box with Nova, and I would consider it to be a bug if Nova violated this (as that's the whole point of route-model binding).